# Express req.params possibility

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Im a fairly noobish programmer and trying to learn express.

I currently have a global array defined

```
var labreport1 = [...]
var labreport2 = [...]
```

I then run a function to call data and drops the success call into the array as an object so labreport1[4] is like a 5000 object json for instance.

So like

```
function getData (x) {...
writeRes(x, res);
return x[4]
...;}

function writeRes(x, z) {
    x[4] = z;
};
```

where z is the response from my data call.

I then used express to send that json object.

so

```
app.get('/labreport1', function(req, res) {
    getData(labreport1);
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    res.json(labreport1[4]);
});
```

this was working all fine and dandy but the rule of programming is if I am copying and pasting the same function over and over again except changing one consistent variable, i should write a function or something right?

Now however, the # of labreports are expanding alot and I do not want to have to copy and paste the app.get for express over and over for each report so I tried to use req.params

```
app.get('/:labreport', function(req, res) {
```

This is where my inexperience is biting me in the butt. I have to drop req.params('labreport') into a variable like reportName right?

if I use req.params('labreport') and access the page as say labreport1, req.params just returns labreport1 as a string. So when I input reportName into my getData function that makes the call and puts the data into the array, its saying at this point my global array is undefined and reportName is a "string" (so it comes back as "labreport1" instead of finding passing the object)

if I drop a debugger and step through my app.get my array is undefined if I use the :labreport. but in my previous original setup, my array was defined properly!

Am I going about this the right way or am I looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

If it's global, then you should be able to get the array like so:

```
global[req.params.labreport]
```

Comment: global[req.params.labreport] comes back as 

global["labreport1"]

which is undefined.

I would need global[labreport1] right?

req.params returns it as a string?

edit; Yea just tested it
just typing in line
global[labreport1] has my array in it but req.params.labreport accessing it via /labreport1 returns with quotes "labreport1" which is not being identified as an array

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FwBg7aw.jpg

It doesnt seem to be working?
req.params.report returns "EMPLEPL"
global["EMPLEPL"] finds nothing despite its found as EMPLEPL?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

Node.js has a different way of declaring global variables. I was using var arr = new array();

if you just declare the variable without var, you end up with a global variable attached to global.

Probably basic noob stuff but I had no idea it was like this in node!

Answer (score 0):

To get the parameters of the URL, you can do `req.params.labreport`

So, your function would be

```
app.get('/:labreport', function(req, res) {
    getData(req.params.labreport);
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    res.json(req.params.labreport[4]);
});
```

You can even make it shorter by declaring it as a variable:

```
app.get('/:labreport', function(req, res) {
    var labreport = req.params.labreport
    getData(labreport);
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    res.json(labreport[4]);
});
```